# Veutify autocomplete hide disabled items

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have disabled some of the items in vuetify's `<v-autocomplete>` using the prop `item-disabled`, naturally these items still appear in the dropdown. How can I, for this particular instance, *hide* those items as well?

[image]

Similar autocompletes appear through the application but not all should behave in similar way, for some instances the disabled items should be shown, for others not. Because of that I went ahead and added class for disabled items. This, however, doesnt seem to be applied and hidden item still appear in the list (probably due to the way vuetify implements dropdowns):

```
<v-autocomplete 
   v-model="selectedItem"
   class="list-hide-disabled"
   :items="items"
   :item-disabled="isItemDisabled">
</v-autocomplete>

::v-deep .list-hide-disabled .v-list-item.v-list-item--disabled {
    display: none;
}

isItemDisabled(item: ListItemModel): boolean {
   return item.isDeleted;
}
```

filtering `:items` doesnt seem to be applicable because it will also hide prior selections, selected items chosen before disabling should still render. The `v-slot:item` also appears to be of no use because even if the content is hidden, it will keep empty box in place of the 'hidden' item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use **class** you have to overwrite an item slot for *v-autocomplete* and applied your class to the item that has an **isDeleted** property

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      selectedItem: null,
      items: [{
        text: 'A',
        isDeleted: false
      }, {
        text: 'B',
        isDeleted: true
      }]
    }
  },
});
```

```css
.list-hide-disabled {
  display: none !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-autocomplete v-model="selectedItem" :items="items" item-disabled="isDeleted">
      <template #item="{item, on, attrs}">
      <v-list-item v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" :class="{'list-hide-disabled': item.isDeleted}">{{item.text}}</v-list-item>
    </template>
    </v-autocomplete>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, however global style will change the behaviour for every single select/autocomplete/combobox in the application. I would like to keep this change for specific instance(s) only, preferably marked by the `list-hide-disabled` class but any reduction of scope will do. Worst case scenario is adding a component `my-autocomplete` and scope it to the component, but it is less than ideal, class or similar would be better.

Comment: @wondra I updated my answer. You were right when trying to overwrite a v-slot but apparently, you make some small mistake that causes a bad display

Comment: Worth pointing out, the template root *has to* be `<v-list-item/>` which is the key difference. When using list-item, it is used as root of the rendered items and can be styled. Using for example `</span>`(like I did) will cause vuetify render extra wrapper which effectively discards all applied classes.